# Atualizar Dados Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update

Pessoal preciso fazer o BD atualizar os seguintes dados deste wireframe via MYSQLi, gostaria de algumas dicas de como proceder.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Melhor por o código real referente a esse esboço, em vez da imagem. A representação gráfica não guarda nenhuma relação com as funções da `mysqli`, o código sim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$marca = trim($_POST["marca"]);
$tipo = trim($_POST["tipo"]);
$quantidade = trim($_POST["quantidade"]);

$atualiza = mysqli_query("UPDATE cigarros SET marca_cigarro = '$marca', tipo_cigarro = '$tipo', quantidade_cigarro = '$quantidade'");

if($atualiza){
echo 'Configurações salvas com sucesso!';
}else{
echo 'Erro ao salvar configurações, tente novamente';
}
?>
```

Lembrando que as colunas que eu usei ali na `query` são para você ter uma base. Troque elas para o nome real das colunas que estão no `MySQL`.

Comment: Valeu Alisson, Salvou!!!